# Not able to send http POST request using axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, axios, mern

I am building a CSV uploader using MERN stack. Using axios for api hitting and multer for handling file uploading. When i try to send the csv file using my client side i am getting BAD REQUEST error.
But when i try to hit the same endpoint with my file through thunderclient it's working completely fine and i am recieving my file under req.file object but with client side request through axios i am recieving this in my req.body object.

```
 body: [Object: null prototype] { myfile: '[object FileList]' }


//Client Side

import React, {useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import './App.css';
const App = () => {
 const [csv, setCsv] = useState({
  file: null
 })
const onFormSubmit = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 const formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('myfile', csv.file);
 const config = {
   headers: {
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
   }
 };
 axios.post("http://localhost:5000/csv_uploader", formData, config)
   .then((response) => {
     alert("The file is successfully uploaded");
   }).catch((error) => {
  });
}

const onChange = (e) => {
setCsv({ file: e.target.files });
}

return (
  <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
   <h1>File Upload</h1>
   <input type="file" className="custom-file-input" name="myfile" onChange= 
   {onChange} />
  {console.log(csv.file)}
  <button className="upload-button" type="submit">Upload to DB</button>
 </form>
 )
}
export default App;



//Server Side
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
 destination: function (req, file, cb) {
   cb(null, __basedir + '/uploads/')
 },
 filename: function (req, file, cb) {
   cb(null, file.filename + "-" + Date.now() + "-" + file.originalname)
 }
})
const csvFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
 file.mimetype.includes('csv') ? cb(null, true) :
   cb('Please upload csv file', false);
}

const upload = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: csvFilter });

app.post('/csv_uploader', upload.single('myfile'), async (req, res) => {
 try {
    if (req.file == undefined) return res.status(400).send({ message: "Please 
    upload a csv file" });
    res.send('CSV UPLOADED');
 } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
 }
})
```

Error showing in browser console
`xhr.js:210 POST http://localhost:5000/csv_uploader 400 (Bad Request)`

Response
`{"message":"Please upload a csv file"}`

[image: Thunderclient body]

Please let me know what i am doing wrong.
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here's some things you can try.

1. change `upload.single('myfile')` to `upload.single('myImage')` to match your input element's name attribute
2. log the req on the server and ensure file isn't received at all
3. remove the multer fileFilter
4. add the thunderclient request body to your question so readers have an example of a successful request

Comment: I tried all the changes but no success and also edited the question with thunderclient body and console log of req object

Comment: Try changing the args for  formData.append('myfile', csv.file) to just ('myfile', csv). Or try sending the file, without being part of formdata,  ie axios.post('...',csv.file). Also try removing the req headers and see if they just get inferred.